# How to remove white space from a field using Search API module

Tags: search

I'm using Search API and Search Views to search the Drupal user database.

One of the fields is phone number where users are able to enter free text.

I can include this field in the search, but the search will not pick up part words.

E.g. 6162 5555 - does not display when I search for 25555 because the index sees these terms as separate words.

Is there a way to strip all the site space (and maybe then brackets) from the field before it is indexed by Search API?

Answer (score 1):

I would use [Computed Fields](https://drupal.org/project/computed_field). Store and display user input with spaces, but index and search computed field too.

> These computed fields are populated with values that you define via PHP code.

So you can simply remove white spaces, or re-format phone number in any way you please, and store a standardised copy of user's phone number. That way both representations will be searchable.

As a small bonus, other modules (like Views, various exporters and connectors or phone integration) would be able to benefit from this too. Bad thing is a slight overhead on reads and saves.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

You need to disable Tokenizer. Then it should work.